# Query to filter 10% data or top 20 whichever is more

Tags: filter, criteria, ms-access-2016, minimum

I have a MS Access table with lots of records. I want to create a query to randomly select 10% of records. However, the minimum count of records should be 20. So, if the total count of records is 180, it should ignore the 10% criteria and filter out minimum 20 records.

I have successfully retrieved the 10% data using the Top 10% return setup. I need to apply the minimum 20 records criteria. Can someone please guide me further.

Answer (score 0):

You must count the records and adjust the SQL manually:

```
Const TopCount   As String = "20"
Const TopPercent As String = "10%"

Dim Sql          As String
Dim TopValue     As String

Dim Records      As DAO.Recordset

Sql = "Select Top {0} * From YourTable"

If DCount("*", "YourTable") > 200 Then
    TopValue = TopPercent
Else
    TopValue = TopCount
End If 
Sql = Replace(Sql, "{0}", TopValue)

Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
```